# CSS Animate an object along a DIV

Tags: css, animation

Thanks in advance for any attempted help.  Here's my goal.

**Current Setup**:
I have an image in a DIV that's basically a straight, vertical line.  The site is done mainly with PHP.

**Goal**:
I want to animate either a horizontal line or other small image along the length of this vertical line based on percentage values I pass somewhere.

[image: Sample Image]

**Possible Options**:
- A transparent DIV on top of the DIV with the image that moves up and down based on a % of the height.

- An image (line or icon) in an adjacent DIV that accomplishes the same movement based on percentage
- If doing this via a percentage is not possible, I could possibly send information when specific points along this path are crossed and use that to update the horizontal line.

**Concerns**:
- If I can achieve this type of animation in a DIV where do I dynamicly pass the percentage information to in order for the DIV to move?

- I'm assuming some solution involving jQuery/Ajax would be needed to update the percentage values so I might have to ask that in another question unless there's a simple method someone could outline.
- A solution that works with a DIV whose height is either a percentage of the container or statically set in px would be ideal.

Thanks again for your help.

- d -

Comment: `#horizline { position: relative; top: 0 }`, then some JS to do your ajax calls to get updated positions and calculate a new `top` offset to set the line to.

Comment: Interesting.  I understand the concept so I "might" be able to work with this after some digging around but still a bit lost to the implementation details....  Thanks for you help.